# How to increase server file upload limit in bemusic?

Tags: php, wamp64

I use WAMP64 Server and I have tried increasing the post_max_size and max_upload_size in the php.ini file of the WAMP Server but still it doesn't work. What to do in this case?
It would be very helpful if anyone could solve this problem.

Comment: You must also increase the body size in your webserver configuration. Google Apache Webserver LimitRequestBody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it probably wasn't the config file, make info.php for check the configuration file. check **Loaded Configuration File** and **upload_max_filesize**

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the WAMPManager menus to do many of these things

[image]

Also remember to use the menus to make sure you are amending the correct php.ini file.

```
wampmanager->php->php.ini
```

This will edit the file in the Apache directory (the correct one to change the web server config). Dont forget to restart Apache after making a change!!! Also done using the menus

```
wampmanager->Apache->Service Administration->restart Service
```